# Appropriate Bluetooth Class of Device/Service (COD) for Proprietary Hardware/Software

Tags: bluetooth

Bluetooth supports a wide range of different device and service types but i'm getting lost trying to determine the most basic one.

Assuming you have a custom proprietary piece of hardware that is supposed to communicate with a custom proprietary piece of software installed on computers or smartphones using a custom proprietary protocol which is the most appropriate COD value to use?

This means it should be avoided that any general purpose Bluetooth software attempts to communicate with the hardware while making the custom service easily discoverable for the custom software.

For example is there something in Bluetooth comparable to custom MIME types like application/vnd.foo?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `0x800500`, that is an unspecified peripheral providing information services.

For more informations you can read the specification at https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/baseband

Just note how the specification uses the term "unspecified" to mean "not classified by this specification".

Comment: The correct link is https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/baseband/